# I mounted an extra partition for a Linux account and found it unmounted after reboot. Why?

Tags: linux, partitioning, mount, automation

I have an extra ext3 primary partition that I wanted to mount for a particular Linux user account. I ran mkdir, mount, chown, and all was good. However, upon reboot I have discovered that the partition is no longer mounted. How can I mount, and keep mounted, an extra partition in Linux? The hard disk is SATA, if that matters. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to edit your [/etc/fstab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fstab) file to include a line detailing the filesystem, mount point and options. [Here's a good post from the ubuntu forums detailing the fstab file](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=283131).

Answer (score 6):

Edit the your /etc/fstab and add a new line that looks similar to the following:

```
/dev/sdb1 /mnt/device auto defaults 1 0
```

- **/dev/sda1** should be the path to the device you want to mount
- **/mnt/device** should be the directory you want to mount the device to
- **auto** can be replaced with the filesystem type of the device you are mounting (e.g. ext3)
- **defaults** can be replaced with options such as ro, noauto, etc. (multiple options should be separated by commas)
- **1** means the backup utility dump will backup the filesystem (0 means it will NOT be backed up)
- **0** tells fsck the order in which the filesystems will be mounted (0 means the filesystem is ignored)

For more information and a list of the options/filesystem types available, you can either 'man fstab' or visit the [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fstab).

Comment: Nice explanation

Comment: Perhaps the most useful option is "noatime", which stops the system updating the access time of a file. This usefully increases the efficiency of the file system, at the expense of knowing if anything has accessed any particular files. I suggest if you have any files that really need this option, then mount them in another file system with noatime on.